# Split a String using strtok groups false tokens

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to read a textfile line by line and to split each line into a token. But when I try to parse

```
D: 0 S: 0
push 0
prti
halt
```

I get an error in the first line.  The result is

```
0: [D:] [0 S] [0] (3 Token)
1: [push] [0] (2 Token)
2: [prti] (1 Token)
3: [halt] (1 Token)
```

but I was expecting

```
0: [D:] [0] [S:] [0] (4 Token) <--
1: [push] [0] (2 Token)
2: [prti] (1 Token)
3: [halt] (1 Token)
```

the second token should be 0 and the third should be S: but as you can see in the first result the second token is "0 s", the 3rd is 0 and there is no 4th token.

I added an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *trimwhitespace(char *str) {
  char *end;
  while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)) str++;
  if(*str == 0) return str; 
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace((unsigned char)*end)) end--;
  end[1] = '\0';
  return str;
}

int main(void) {

    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    int tokencounter = 0;
    char *token;
    int linecounter;
    int address = 0;

    char *tokentemp;

    fp = fopen("test.asm", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) exit(1);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {   

        token = strtok(line, " ");
        tokencounter = 0;

        printf("%d: ", linecounter);

        while( token != NULL ) {

            token = trim( token );
            printf( "[%s] ", token );
            tokencounter++;                
            token = strtok(NULL, line);           

        }

        printf("(%d Token)\n", tokencounter);

        linecounter++;

    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line) free(line);
    exit(1);

}
```

Comment: Fyi, there is no `trim` in this code; only `trimwhitespace`. For future reference, it's *impossible* to introduce "typos" during posting when copy/pasting *real code* that compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second call to `strtok` uses wrong arguments.

Instead of

```
token = strtok(NULL, line);
```

write

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

If you use `line` as parameter for the delimiter, then the second call will start with `line` starting with `:`, such that `strtok` will split upon `:` first (and not on  as you expected).